# Wamp Local Wordpress site: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: wordpress, apache, wamp, wampserver

I have a live HTTPS wordpress site running. Recently I tried to WAMP it locally to test out some other themes, Git & stuff, but the site wouldn't load, returning ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED errors.

1. The live site is hosted by Siteground, running with SSL (HTTPS).
2. I have set up the database correctly. (I'm sure because it used to return database connection error and then I fixed it)
3. I used to get Invalid command 'AddOutputFilterByType', 'Header' in Apache error logs. I then turned on the mod_filter and mod_headers in Wamp, and **now I still get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error in browser, but the error log does not add new messages.**
4. This is **the only local site which wouldn't run**. I have other Wamp sites run with no issues.
5. The only clue for me could be the Apache access log, which is pasted as follows:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 - - [17/May/2016:16:04:41 +1000] "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1463465081.0992779731750488281250 HTTP/1.0" 200 -
   127.0.0.1 - - [17/May/2016:16:04:28 +1000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 -
   127.0.0.1 - - [17/May/2016:16:04:27 +1000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 -
   127.0.0.1 - - [17/May/2016:16:04:41 +1000] "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1463465081.0982780456542968750000 HTTP/1.0" 200 25
   127.0.0.1 - - [17/May/2016:16:30:11 +1000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 435
   127.0.0.1 - - [17/May/2016:16:30:13 +1000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 435
   ```
6. I have tried to disabled wp-cron but it couldn't fix the problem.

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Do you also have `mod_rewrite` activated ?

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you tried all the obvious browsers and do you get the same error from all of them?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the browser Cache and Cookies?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for reply. Yes, mod_rewrite is activated and the problem persist in all browsers.

Comment: Being as its WordPress, I assume yo have been through the database and changed all the urls stored in there from `www.livesite.com` to your local address?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I use Migrate DB plugin to download the DB with urls changed.